# Меняется цвет statusbar после просмотра полноэкранной картинки в CXPhotoBrowser

Tags: objective-c, ios

Для просмотра полноэкранной галереи использую [CXPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/ChrisXu1221/CXPhotoBrowser)

Однако, после двойного нажатия при просмотре (режим приближения картинки) и возврата в предыдущее состояние - цвет StatusBar изменяется на dafult вместо моего оранжевого:

**ДО УВЕЛИЧЕНИЯ**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ПОСЛЕ УВЕЛИЧЕНИЯ**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же этот черный цвет остается потом в приложении до его перезагрузки.

Кто сталкивался с подобной ситуацией? Как можно вернуть цвет StatusBar?

Comment: Пока что точно не могу что-то сказать по Вашей проблеме. Но могу посоветовать использовать альтернативный вариант. https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser/blob/master/README.md .

Comment: Не сложилось с этой библиотекой у меня. Не смог настроить.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй в ViewController добавить этот метод:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```